# Regular mapping space vs continuous mapping space for affine schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homology

Let $A$ and $B$ be Zariski open affine sub-schemes of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{n}$ and $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^m$ respectively. We denote the infinite symmetric product of $B$ by $Sym^{\infty}(B)$. Let $X:= \varinjlim\limits_{U\subset A \text{ Zariski open}}Map(U, Sym^{\infty}(B))$ where maps is the continuous maps with the compact open topology. Let $Y:=\varinjlim\limits_{U\subset A \text{ Zariski open}}Map_{reg}(U, Sym^{\infty}(B))$. Here $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ consisting of regular maps. Is there a way to see whether the natural map $Y\rightarrow X$ induces isomorphisms on the homologies on the certain ranges or not?

My expectations is that it might be isomorphism for dimensions less than or equal to the Krull dimension of $B$. Is there an obvious counter-example for this statement?

For example when $B=\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^m$ by Dold-Thom $Sym^{\infty}B$ is contractible, so reduced homology groups of the continuous mapping space is going to be zero, how about the algebraic ones?

Comment: What topology are you using on $\mathrm{Sym}^{\infty}(B)$ for continuous maps? The topology induced from $\mathbb{C}^m$?

Comment: @Kapil The weak topology induced from $Sym^n(B)$ which itself is induced by the complex numbers.